# Как добавить исключение в регулярку?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

По сути нужна регулярка типа `="([^"]*)"`, но с тем исключением, чтобы можно было экранировать `"`, по типу `="text\"text"` и получить  `text\"text` из группы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такая:

```
/"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"/gm
```

[Проверка](https://regex101.com/r/JtKNcv/1)

А если нужна группа без кавычек, то:

```
/"((?:\\.|[^\\"])*)"/gm
```

Comment: Если не затруднит, можете пояснить, что делает `?:`?

Comment: @megorit Это незахватывающая группа. Т.е. то, что внутри, не попадет в результат. Если убрать `?:`, то последний символ попадет в выборку.